# Lazarus compatible with Delphi 5?

Tags: delphi, compatibility, lazarus, delphi-5

We use Delphi 5 on Windows in our school, and of course it's good to have at home, too. But since I have Ubuntu and I don't want to either use ancient software or pay hundreds of dollars I will have to use Lazarus (which seems to be pretty nice). But it has not the same compiler and maybe not the same libraries, so will the code written in Delphi 5 compile with Lazarus? How much are they compatible?

Comment: Delphi 5 is 15 years old so I would say that almost everything in FPC runtime should be compatible. Lazarus LCL does a few things differently, so there you might need to do some modifications, but it depends on what you're doing.

Comment: What things are different for example? Like major differences in the api or in the language?

Comment: @Kapichu There will be too many to list here and and exhaustive list probably doesn't exist.  Without almost any exception, it's probaly safe to say that nearly all of the differences will be things that Lazarus *can* do that Delphi 5 *cannot*.  Even some things that would today be considered core basics in Delphi did not exist in Delphi 5 - one example is the `StrUtils` unit that provides basic utility functions for string manipulation.

Comment: @J... So I can (mostly) consider Lazarus as a superset of Delphi?

Comment: @Kapichu Mostly, yes - a superset of Delphi 5, at least.  Most anything you write in Delphi 5 will be seamless or trivial to port to Lazarus.  The reverse is not true.

Comment: I would accept that as an answer if it was one...

Comment: @Kapichu Actually, I just noticed that you're developing on Ubuntu - if you're cross-compiling for Win32 what I've said should be true.  This may also be true for core VCL/RTL stuff if compiling for Linux but I would expect there may be differences if trying to port Delphi 5/Win32 projects to Lazarus/Linux.  I don't know what differences exist in those libraries.

Comment: There are lots of differences, and lots in common. You likely won't take D5 projects and make them work unchanged in fpc/Lazarus. Not that simple.

Answer (score 2):

I belive it should just don't forget to use Delphi mode in Lazarus.

In "Project Options -> Compiler Options -> Parsing" select "Syntax mode" to "Delphi (-Mdelphi)"

Now if you will be automatically converting Delphi project into Lazarus one using menu "Tools -> Convert Delphi project to Lazarus project" Lazarus should automatically set Delphi mode.

Anywhay the only problems you might expirience is that some functions might have been moved to different units. This is mostly related that Delphi 7 with which Lazarus is compleetly compatible had some functions moved from one unit to another. So reading some old documentation about porting projects from Delphi 5 to Delphi 7 might come in handy.

Comment: Can I also convert a Lazarus project to Delphi?

Comment: Not directly. The reason why Lazarus has ability to convert Delphi project into lazarus one is to atract as many Delphi developers into using it. And since Delphi is still most often used Objective Pascal development tool there is no interest in implementing such feature into Delphi. So I'm afraid you are out of luck on this. Anywhay I recomend you learn to code in such way that you split your core code from UI code (VCL). Why? Doing so you will increase the chances for your core code to be crosscompatible with both Delphi and Lazarus. This could also help you supporting multiple platforms.

Comment: Object Pascal is not Objective Pascal. Free Pascal supports both though :-)

Comment: @SilverWarior +1 for seperating UI logic between VCL code.